# How to shorten std::vector?

Tags: vector, calloc, shorthand

Instead of doing this for calloc:

`TCHAR *sText = (TCHAR *) calloc(1024, sizeof(TCHAR));`

I have this at the top of my C++ file:

`#define tcalloc(nCharacters) (TCHAR*)calloc(nCharacters,sizeof(TCHAR))`

so I can more easily write this:

`TCHAR *sText = tcalloc(1024);`

Now, how do I do a shorthand for my std::vector statement? This is my code:

`std::vector <TCHAR>sText(1024,0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

```
typedef std::vector<TCHAR> tcVec;
#define init_1k_charVector tcVec(1024,0)
int main(int, char**)
{
    tcVec sText(1024,0);
    tcVec sText2 = init_1k_charVector;   
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, now how do I not put in ',0' and have it initialized to zeros?

Comment: i personally wouldnt 'hide' this fact. at some point it might be convinient, on some other point it might be confusing. i edit the answere in case ;)